# Backbone.js Router doesn't fire on page init

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events, backbone-routing

i have a quite simple backbone router and everything works fine so far. Except when i reload/direct enter the url i.e. `http://mydomain.com/#list/50fadc41125b0`
I've tried nearly everything now without any positiv results at all.

```
myRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "list/:id": "getList",      
        "*actions": "defaultRoute" // not needed right now
    },
    getList: function (id) {
        console.log ("test");
    }
});
```

i tried it this way as well without any difference

```
// init router
router = new myRouter;
router.on('route:getList', function (id) {
    [...]
});
```

i have no i idea how to make this work! 
hopefully someone has an answer for me!

**EDIT:**

i also start the history

```
Backbone.history.start();
```

Comment: Do you start the history? http://backbonejs.org/#History-start

Comment: yes! i tested it on nearly every position now ;)

Comment: Are you creating the router before you call `Backbone.history.start()`? A fiddle showing the problem would be helpful.

Comment: thx, that was solving my problem ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

due a mistake i was initializing my router asynchronous in a fetch success statement so `Backbone.history.start()` had nothing to initialize.

thx to the user Lukas for reminding me to create the router before.